Why is there only one normal ultrafilter in L[U]?
OK, be patient with me if you recognize my name and wonder how I can fail to know this -- it's been a long time.
"Everyone knows" that, if $U$ is a normal ultrafilter on a measurable cardinal $\kappa$, then in $L[U]$ there is a unique normal ultrafilter, namely $U$.
OK, so working inside $L[U]$, let's build up a different one, $W$.  We'll start with the club filter on $\kappa$.  Now pick a stationary costationary subset $A$ of $\kappa$, and if $A$ is not in $U$, then throw $A$ into $W$, but if $A$ is in $U$, throw $\kappa\setminus A$ into $W$.
Now iterate through all unspoken-for subsets (sets $A$ such that neither $A$ nor $\kappa\setminus A$ is in the closure of $W$ under $\lt\kappa$-sized intersections) in the obvious way, throwing the first unspoken-for subset into $W$ and closing under $\lt\kappa$-sized intersections.
When you're done, don't you have a $\kappa$-complete normal ultrafilter on $\kappa$ that's different from $U$?
It's probably something obvious :-)

How do you ensure normality? (It's more than just $<\kappa$-closure.)

Because we threw in the club filter at the bottom.

But why should it be closed under diagonal intersections?

Ah, this may be what I was missing.  I thought if all measure-1 sets were stationary that was enough to get normality.

If we recognise your name? I don't recall anyone called "user15141416" in any of the conferences I've been to lately.

Heh heh.  I'm not super familiar with this site.  I thought it might use my real name.  (I suppose I can change that in settings if I want?)

The issue is normality. It's not enough to contain the club filter; you can, via a greedy construction (essentially what you're doing here!), produce a non-normal ultrafilter containing the club filter. Normality is a difficult-to-enforce condition since obstacles to normality can (do) arise at limit stages, with a diagonal intersection being "small" even though no individual set was seen to be problematic.
EDIT: as spaceisdarkgreen points out below, even $<\kappa$-completeness is not obviously guaranteed by your construction; the point is that closing under "large" (= infinite but still size-$<\kappa$) intersections might result in the emptyset even if no particular set caused an issue in the construction. Of course normality is even stronger, so it's still reasonable to focus on normality in this answer, but I misspoke initially.

I believe you that you can greedily produce a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter like that, but I'm blanking on how... clearly not getting stuck with emptysets while 'taking the closure under $<\kappa$-sized interections' must use something particular to measurable cardinals.

@spaceisdarkgreen You're right - I don't even see how to ensure $<\kappa$-completeness. Fixed!
